# Excel MDX expression filter for Same Period Last Month

Tags: excel, mdx

I have managed to create a filter for OLAP Cube for the 'last 30 days' as described here: http://blogs.socha.com/2010/05/sliding-date-ranges-with-excel-2010.html .
Now I would need to get the 'Same Period Last Month' filter done the same way (so I can drag and drop it in the pivot table to filter any sales data). Ideally it would show just totals, not day by day data. I tried many different expressions but since I'm very new to MDX nothing works for me.

I would appreciate you help.

Thanks,
Maciej

Comment: When you say 'Same Period Last Month', the same period like what do you want to see?

Comment: Basically if today's date is 25/02/2014, then I would like to see the sales data for the same period of last month being 01/01/2014 - 25/01/2014, ie. first 25 days of pervious month. That way I can compare this month's performance (month-to-date) to the performance of last month for the same number of days (25).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably use something like

```
Filter( 
    [Date].[Date].[Date], 
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value >= 
          DateSerial(Year(DateAdd('m', -1, VBA![Date]())),
                     Month(DateAdd('m', -1, VBA![Date]())),
                     1
                    ) 
    AND [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value <= DateAdd('m', -1, VBA![Date]())
)
```

Here, `DateAdd('m', -1, VBA![Date]()` is one month before today, which is the end date. And the start date is calculated from this end date using the year and month of this date and 1 as the day within the month, and feeding these into `DateSerial` to make a date.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510163.aspx for a list of VBA functions (among them many date functions) supported by MDX.